# Angular CLI Creating files in the same folder error

Tags: angular, webpack, command-line-interface

Am having this issue, where when I generate components with Angular CLI instead of generating them in the same folder I have CD in it generate them in the App folder. Lets say I have CD to App/Recipe and I use this "ng g c recipe-item" it will be generated in App folder instead of Recipe.
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you want to generate a new component called recipe-item inside of the recipe directory:

```
ng g c recipe/recipe-item
```

See page 2: https://cli.angular.io/reference.pdf -> ng generate -> Valid types: -> component

Answer (score 0):

as shown [on angular-cli page](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#generating-components-directives-pipes-and-services)

> components support relative path generation

try using

```
ng g component recipe-item
```

Comment: From the documentation it shows that, but when I try it it doesn't work. I have edited the quoin by adding a screen shot of the same.

Comment: `src/app/new-cmp/new-cmp.component.html` is created corrected by the `ng g component recipe-item`.  check your folder structure once.

Comment: What I want to achieve here is src/app/test/newcmp.component.html. I am already at in the folder Geralds-MacBook-Pro:test gbrigens$.

Comment: it is going to create a separate folder for your component (that's how cli works).   if you want to achieve `src/app/test/newcmp.component.html` then you have to manually add the files (which i won't recommend). when you would have executed `ng g component test` then `test` folder with all the component files were created. so if you want to have `new-cmp` component file in test folder, then you have to manually do it . running `ng g component xyz` would create `xyz` folder with all the component files. hope I'm clear.

Comment: Yea, you are right, if I don't want to create a folder for it I will use "--flat" flag, If you have time check out this tutorial from mindspace https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DBjPIabiRNg min31 the guy generates components in the same path.